# Synchronizing execution of multiple tasks

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

How do I sync the execution of multiple tasks?

I need all task to reach the same instruction before they can continue their execution.

Every task has to wait for the others to reach that instruction before going on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for [`Barrier`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.barrier%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Enables multiple tasks to cooperatively work on an algorithm in parallel through multiple phases.

and,

> A group of tasks cooperate by moving through a series of phases, where each in the group signals it has arrived at the `Barrier` in a given phase and implicitly waits for all others to arrive. The same `Barrier` can be used for multiple phases.

(The example on the `Barrier` page shows four tasks all running the same code - but that's not by any means a requirement)

Comment: Which is the difference between Task.WaitAll and Barrier?

Comment: With the barrier, the tasks haven't completed - they still (each) have their own work to carry on with after the barrier has been passed. With `WaitAll`, all of those tasks have completed - if there's more work to do (for multiple tasks) you need to create a new set of tasks to do that work.

Answer (score 1):

If you've got a variety of different tasks to wait for, then [`Task.WaitAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270695%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

If lots of instances of the same task then [`parallel.foreach`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is an easy wait to run them.

Comment: Can I use Task.WaitAll from inside a task to wait all the others?

Comment: Task.WaitAll adn Barrier have different usage: Task.WaitAll would be from outside the tasks, guaranteeing that they've completed before you move on to the next step in your main thread. Barrier gives "Milestones" that a task will reach internally, then wait for other tasks to reach the same point before moving on. It doesn't mean that the task is complete, just that it reached that important point.

Comment: WaitAll() does indeed not allow for "... they can continue their execution"

Comment: @Sam -and to directly answer, no, a task **shouldn't** call `WaitAll` on a set of tasks that includes itself. That would never complete.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Ooh, a deadlock with cycle length of 1, you don't see that often. :-) (Usually, there are two tasks waiting on each other.)